# Random Number Program Using Function c++

Tags: c++

I have created a simple random number program that takes 5 inputs and outputs different random numbers.

A user can enter 5 vowels irrespective of case and the function calculates a random number based on the input.

Possible Incomes: a A a A e

Possible Outcomes: 1 2 3 19 25

Problem: I do not get different numbers when I enter the same vowel more than once, but this is not the same when I put a breakpoint and run my code in debugger mode

Following is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int createRandomFromChar(char inputChar);

int main()
{
    char answer;
   
    char inputOne, inputTwo, inputThree, inputFour, inputFive;

    cout << endl <<
        "This program plays a simple random number guessing game." << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << endl << "Enter 5 vowel characters (a,e,i,o,u or A,E,I,O,U) separated by spaces: ";
        cin >> inputOne >> inputTwo >> inputThree >> inputFour >> inputFive;
        cin.ignore();
       
        int randomNumberOne = createRandomFromChar(inputOne);
        int randomNumberTwo = createRandomFromChar(inputTwo);
        int randomNumberThree = createRandomFromChar(inputThree);
        int randomNumberFour = createRandomFromChar(inputFour);
        int randomNumberFive = createRandomFromChar(inputFive);
        

        cout << "The random numbers are " << left << 
            setw(3) << randomNumberOne << left <<
            setw(3) << randomNumberTwo << left <<
            setw(3) << randomNumberThree << left << setw(3) << randomNumberFour 
            << left << setw(3) << randomNumberFive;

       

        cout << endl << "Do you want to continue playing? Enter 'Y' or 'y' to continue playing: "
            << endl;
        
       
        answer = cin.get();

        cin.ignore();
    }
    while ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'));

}

int createRandomFromChar(char inputChar)
{
    srand(time(0));

    int n1 = 1 + (rand() % 20);
    int n2 = 21 + (rand() % 20);
    int n3 = 41 + (rand() % 20);
    int n4 = 61 + (rand() % 20);
    int n5 = 81 + (rand() % 20);

    if ((inputChar == 'a') || (inputChar == 'A'))
    {
        return n1;

    }
    else if ((inputChar == 'e') || (inputChar == 'E'))
    {
        return n2;

    }
    else if ((inputChar == 'i') || (inputChar == 'I'))
    {
        return n3;

    }
    else if ((inputChar == 'o') || (inputChar == 'O'))
    {
        return n4;

    }
    else if ((inputChar == 'u') || (inputChar == 'U'))
    {
        return n5;

    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: `time(0)` returns time in seconds. Calling it several times in a second will yield the same seed and so the same random sequence. When you put a breakpoint you force the increase of the time interval and so you'll get different seeds. Bottom line: you should put `srand(time(0));` in `main()` before the calls to `createRandomFromChar`.

Comment: Even better than fixing `srand` - in C++ it's recomended to use the <random> utilities. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get different numbers when I enter the same vowel more than once, but this is not the same when I put a breakpoint and run my code in debugger mode

It's because of this:

```
int createRandomFromChar(char inputChar)
{
    srand(time(0));  // <- the culprit
```

Every time you call `createRandomFromChar` you reseed (restart) the pseudo random number generator with the value returned from `time(0)`. If you run the program without stepping through the debugger it will run through the program in a few microseconds and `time(0)` will return the same value every time - so, you will get the same sequence of numbers from `rand()` afterwards. When you step through the debugger, you will likely take your time and therefore `time(0)` will return different values which will result in different number sequences coming from `rand()`.

The solution is to only call `std::srand(std::time(nullptr));` *once* during the whole program run. You can do it in the beginning of `main` and then never again.

---

---

Another option is to use one of the better pseudo random number generators, like [`std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine), that was added to C++ in C++11 and one of the distributions that tagged along with them, like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). These generators are pretty fast and have portable statistical properties which `rand()` doesn't have. Note: You should only seed these once per program run too.

Example usage:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string_view>

// A better pseudo random number generator than using rand() (+ srand()). 
// This is here seeded by a call to an instance of `std::random_device`:
static std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());

int createRandomFromChar(char inputChar) {
    // a string_view over the valid characters:
    static std::string_view chars{"aeiou"};

    // a distribution to turn random numbers into the range [1,20]:
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 20);

    // turn inputChar into lowercase:
    inputChar = static_cast<char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(inputChar)));

    // find the position of the inputChar in the string_view:
    if(auto pos = chars.find(inputChar); pos != std::string_view::npos) {
        // multiply the position in the string_view with
        // (dist.max() - dist.min() + 1) which is 20, so
        //  'a' becomes 0 * 20 => 0
        //  'e' becomes 1 * 20 => 20
        //  'i' becomes 2 * 20 => 40  etc...
        int letter_start = static_cast<int>(pos) * (dist.max() - dist.min() + 1);

        // get a random number in the range [1,20]:
        int randomNumber = dist(prng);

        // return the result:
        return letter_start + randomNumber;
    }

    // inputChar was not found in the string_view, return 0:
    return 0;
}
```

You could also simplify your `main` a bit by using arrays instead of separate variables:

```
int main() {
    char inputs[5]; // all inputs

    std::cout
        << "Enter " << std::size(inputs)
        << " vowel characters (a,e,i,o,u or A,E,I,O,U) separated by spaces: ";

    // extract one char at a time:
    for(char& inp : inputs) {
        if(!(std::cin >> inp)) {
            std::cerr << "error in input, bye bye.\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // all results:
    int rndNumbers[std::size(inputs)];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < std::size(inputs); ++i) {
        rndNumbers[i] = createRandomFromChar(inputs[i]);
    }

    std::cout << "The random numbers are ";
    for(int num : rndNumbers) {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(3) << num;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted. Based on your explanation I just moved the srand(time(0)); to the main() function and it works absolutely fine now